# How to start IIS Express manually with a virtual path?

Tags: powershell, iis-express

We have a bunch of web applications which may be started with a script on the command line. The script uses the Cassini web server and runs it with the relevant `/port`, `/path` and `/vpath` command line arguments. So far so good.

Now some of us have upgraded their machines and got VS 2013 instead of VS 2012. Even though they can continue and use Cassini many want to work with IIS Express instead and use the same script, which now must be able to start IIS Express.

And here lies my problem. IIS Express and Cassini both have the `/port` and `/path` command line arguments, but the `/vpath` argument is unsupported by IIS Express (why remains a mystery to me).

My question is simple - can IIS Express be started with the virtual path? The only solution that comes to my mind is:

1. Start IIS Express with `/port` and `/path`.
2. Parse the command line to extract the auto generated config file path.
3. Modify the config file to add the relevant virtual directory.

And of course, this should be done automatically by the script. (I have already solved the problem of IIS Express expecting a keyboard input of 'Q' to terminate - it is started as a powershell background job).

Anyway, I am reluctant to implement this solution, feeling this is not a very good approach.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember what the vpath parameter does in Cassini, but of course in IIS (Express) you can not start an instance of a virtual directory, you also start the site that contains the virtual directory.

So set up multiple sites in IIS Express and start the one you need.

If you have a single site and multiple cases where a virtual directory points to different location, you can use `$env:ProgramFiles\IIS Express\appcmd.exe` to change that before starting the site.

Or maybe I don't understand your problem?

Comment: IIS express is started on the command line using /path and /port arguments. This generates the config file with '/' vpath. Do you suggest to modify the file manually? I can do that, but then the user is no longer able to just run the iis express the way (s)he used to with cassini.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Why do you need a vpath? I would set up all sites I need and then start them by name or Id. Yes that may be different from what you've done before. Think of IIS Express as IIS without a GUI. You don't have a change a file manually, use appcmd.exe to adjust the settings, if needed on the fly, do it in your start-script.